# ModuleNotFoundError in python code - cannot find custom class in console app

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a python console app that includes imports of a custom class I'm using. Everytime I run my app I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'DataServices'.

Can you help?

Provided below is my folder structure:

```
ETL
 Baseball
  Baseball_DataImport.py
 DataServices
  DataService.py
  ConfigServices.py
  PageDataMode.py
  SportType.py
```

Here is the import section from the Baseball_DataImport.py file. This is the file when I run I get the error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
import requests
import BaseballEntity
import mechanize
import re
from time import sleep
import logging
import time
import datetime
from functools import wraps
import json
import DataServices.DataService - Error occurs here
```

Here is my DataService.py file:

```
import pymongo
import json
import ConfigServices
import PageDataModel
#from SportType import SportType
class DataServices(object):
      AppConfig: object
      def __init__(self):
          AppConfig = ConfigServices.ConfigService()
          #print(AppConfig)

      #def GetPagingDataBySport(self,Sport:SportType):
      def GetPagingDataBySport(self):
          #if Sport == SportType.BASEBALL:
            pagingData = []
            pagingData.append(PageDataModel.PageDataModel("", 2002, 2))
            pagingData.append(PageDataModel.PageDataModel("", 2003, 2))
            
            return pagingData
```

[image]

Comment: The name of your file is DataService.py and the class name is `DataServices`. Thus, the import should be `import DataService.DataServices`. The file goes first and class inside of that file second.

Comment: Similar error: No module named 'DataService'

Answer (score 0):

It might seem that your structure is:

```
Baseball
  Baseball_DataImport.py
Dataservices
  Dataservice.py
```

Maybe you need to do `from Dataservices.Dataservice import DataServices`

Edit:

I created the folder structure, and the method I showed you works:
[image: Structure]

Here's the implementation
[image: Implementation]

Dataservice.py only contains:

```
class DataServices():
  pass
```

Comment: Similar error: No module named 'DataServices

Comment: Can you edit the part of the folder structure to see if it is different from what I guessed?

Comment: This answer looks like it should work. You could try including an empty `__init__.py` file in the `DataServices` directory.

Comment: @purple it's python 3, it doesn't need `__init__` right?

Comment: Same issue. @purple I also removed the __init__.py file as well. Now I'm am using a virtual environment. Would that have any impact?

Comment: @BrandonMichaelHunter can you show us your folder structure in more detail? Maybe we are giving you the wrong import statement

Comment: image added see my original post

Comment: It worked once I moved the DataServices folder under the Baseball folder. But that is not what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try copieing the Dataservice.py into the Projectfolder with the main.py?

Comment: I do not have a main.py and yes, I've tried this. Didn't work